# Finding all unitary ring homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Find all unitary ring homomorphisms $\phi: \mathbb Z[X]/(X^2-1)\to \mathbb Z_8$.

I know that they can be constructed using the universal property of the polynomial ring but I have a different and less rigorous solution which I want to be checked:

$\phi$ is solely determined by its image on $X$ since its unitarity sets the image of $\mathbb Z$. So lets say $\phi(X)=n\in\mathbb Z_8$ - this means that there can be at most 8 different unitary ring homomorphisms. But $1=\phi(1)=\phi(X^2)=\phi(X)^2=n^2$, so $n\in\{1,3,5,7\}$. And if $n^2$ is in the same coset as $1$ in $\mathbb Z_8$ we get (I will abuse the notation and forget about writing $[r]$ or $\bar r$ for $r=a,b,c,d,n$):

$\phi(aX+b)\phi(cX+d)=(an+b)(cn+d)=\\ac+bd+n(ad+bc)$

which is the same as

$\phi((aX+b)(cX+d))=\phi(acX^2+X(ad+bc)+bd)=\phi(ac+bd+X(ad+bc))\\=ac+bd+n(ad+bc)$

So indeed for $n^2=1$ we get 4 unitary ring homomorphisms.

> Is there any mistake in the argument? And if so, can it be fixed easily?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are four such homomorphisms. Your idea is right, but it can (and should) be made more rigorous.

Suppose you have $\phi$; compose it with the canonical homomorphism $\pi\colon\mathbb{Z}[X]\to\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-1)$. Then $\phi\pi$ is uniquely determined by the image of $X$; say $\phi\pi(X)=a$ and the fact that the action on integers is the canonical one (because there's only one homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_8$). We need that $\phi\pi(X^2-1)=0$, that is, $a^2-1=0$.

The squares of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_8$ are $0^2=0$, $1^2=1$, $2^2=4$, $3^2=1$, $4^2=0$, $5^2=1$, $6^2=4$, $7^2=1$.

Therefore we can only have $a\in\{1,3,5,7\}$. This shows we have *at most* four homomorphisms.

Now, consider $\psi_a\colon\mathbb{Z}[X]\to\mathbb{Z}_8$ uniquely defined by $\psi_a(X)=a\in\{1,3,5,7\}$ and the unique possible action on the integers. Its kernel contains $(X^2-1)$, so we are done, because any of the possible four homomorphisms $\psi_a$ induces a homomorphism of the kind you're looking for, by the homomorphism theorem.

Comment: Could you explain more how my solution isn't rigorous enough? That is the part I do not understand: I think I have shown that every unitary homomorphism must look like ... and each of those possibilities is a unitary homomorphism. To me, your proof just sounds like rephrasing mine.

Comment: @Buh Basically, you only showed there are at most four homomorphisms.